# MoSync IDE: how to run apk in Bluestacks?

Tags: eclipse, mosync, bluestacks

I'm trying out the MoSync IDE (special version of Eclipse to develop cross-browser Android and iOS apps with HTML/Javascript).

It currently uses the standard SDK Android emulator which is rediculously slow. I found Bluestacks which is a lightning-fast android emulator.

I already found out how to use Bluestacks with Phonegap from within Eclipse (by using the `adb connect` command), but I can't figure out if it's even possible to test apps on Bluestacks from within the MoSync IDE...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This works on Mac, and I see no reason why it should not also work on Windows:

- Start Bluestacks
- Run *MOSYNCDIR*/bin/android/adb connect localhost:10001, where *MOSYNCDIR* is your MoSync installation directory
- In the MoSync IDE, click the tiny arrow next to the **Select Target Device** toolbar item and in the dropdown select **Scan for Android USB device**
- If properly connected, a dialog pops up with a list of connected devices. Select *localhost:10001* and click **Ok**
- To actually run on the emulator, select a project in the **Project Explorer** (usually the leftmost panel in the IDE). Then click the **Send to Target Device** toolbar item.